# Python xlsxwriter: Changing individual cell highlight colour

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am writing code in Python using the xlsxwriter module.
My problem is somewhat like other questions here, but with a small twist. I am wanting to change the highlight colour of SPECIFIC INDIVIDUAL cells in Excel. Some cells will already have data entered into them, and I wish to keep that data.

The following is my approach so far:

```
## Highlights appropriate cells
row = 0
col = 0

blue_fmt = workbook.add_format()
blue_fmt.set_pattern(1)
blue_fmt.set_bg_color('#0000FF')

yellow_fmt = workbook.add_format()
yellow_fmt.set_pattern(1)
yellow_fmt.set_bg_color('#FFFF00')

black_fmt = workbook.add_format()
black_fmt.set_pattern(1)
black_fmt.set_bg_color('#000000')
```

I am lost as to how I can instruct my program to highlight specific cells without removing its contents. At the moment, I am thinking some form of iteration would do the trick, but I am worried about losing data already entered into certain cells.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Any help or hints are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I instruct my program to highlight specific cells without removing its contents.

You can't* write formatting and data separately in XlsxWriter. You will need to write the cell format to the cell when you write the data.

(*) It is possible to add [conditional formatting to a range of cells](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_conditional_formats.html) after you have written them.

Comment: Thanks a lot - ended up using conditional formatting with no_blanks and blanks as needed.